# nginx one domain and multiple projects setting alias

Tags: laravel, nginx, routes, vue.js

I want to use one domain to map different project.

mydomain.com.tw => /var/www/project1/public
mydomain.com.tw/test => /var/www/project2

but **mydomain.com.tw/project2/detail** always direct to mydomain.com.tw project route.

project1 => laravel
project2 => vue and using vue-route

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name mydomain.dev;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
root /var/www/project1/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /lottery {
    alias /var/www/project2/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Can you use a subdomain instead? (mydomain.dev and project2.mydomain.dev).

Comment: @Lucas No, because need to use same local storage item.

Comment: Have you tried use another browser ou clear the browser DNS cache? Sometimes this happen to me.

Comment: @Lucas thanks your suggest, i solve by [this](https://gist.github.com/Maras0830/dc6f627eba005bdfc6b741f7f2ea3178)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question.

Solution:

https://gist.github.com/Maras0830/dc6f627eba005bdfc6b741f7f2ea3178